# Show that $(f_n(x))_{n\in \mathbb{n}}$ converge pointwise in $Q \cap [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $(f_n(x))_{n\in \mathbb{n}}$ converge pointwise in $Q \cap [a,b]$, if we define $$f_n: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

such that $|f_n(x)| \leq 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $x \in [a,b]$

I tried to prove it but without sucess. Is this true?, I feel that I need to funtions to be continuos and then using arzela-ascoli using the density of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

As written it is not true, because for all $x$ we can define $f_n(x)=1$ if $n$ is even and $f_n(x)=0$ is $n$, and then there is no $x$ for which $f_n(x)$ converges.

However, by the Cantor diagonal method, you can extract a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ of $f_n$ such that $f_{n_k}(q)$ will converge for each rational number $q$.